# BibTeX: Putting a \href around a title leads to unwanted use of "title style" (instead of the desired "sentence style")

Tags: bibtex, hyperref

I'm trying to have titles link to articles in bibliography entries by putting a `\href` around them that with the link. However, when I do this, it results in words in the title not getting properly put in lower case. An obvious solution would be to just put the titles in the bib file with the capitalization called for by the bibliography style, but I was wondering if there's a simple way to make BibTeX format the titles as it does normally without having to fix the titles by hand.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{my.bib}
    @unpublished{Sample,
        Author = {Sample},
        Title = {\href{}{A Title in Title Case}},
        Year = {0000},
        Note = {Note}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \nocite{Sample}
    \bibliography{my}
\end{document}
```

This produces undesired capitalization:

[1] Sample. A Title in Title Case. Note, 0000.

Leaving out the \href in the title produces the desired capitalization:

[1] Sample. A title in title case. Note, 0000.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fix your problem my not directly writing `\href`: You provide a link to the entry, so semantically it belongs into the `Url` field:

```
@unpublished{Sample,
    Author = {Sample},
    Title = {A Title in Title Case},
    Year = {0000},
    Url = {...},
    Note = {Note}
}
```

Then you only need a `\bibliographystyle` which makes the `title` a link to the `url`. You can create this yourself:
In your TeX installation you can find the file with the `plain` style, `plain.bst` [(You can also find it on CTAN)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/plain.bst). Copy this into the directory of your TeX file under the name `link.bst`. This will be our starting point.

At first, you have to add the `url` field:
At the top of the file `link.bst` you find a list starting with

```
ENTRY
  { address
    author
```

Below `type`, add a line

```
    url
```

Now BibTeX knows about `url`, but ignores the field.
To add the link, search the block

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
    { title "t" change.case$ }
  if$
}
```

This block is responsible for showing the title. Replace it by

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
    { title "t" change.case$
      url empty$
        { }
        { "\href{" url * "}{" * swap$ * "}" * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

This will put `\href{<url>}{...}` around the title if a `Url` was given.

If you save the changes you can use `\bibliographystyle{link}` to use the new style.
In your MWE, you also have to replace

```
\usepackage{natbib}
```

by

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
```

because `link` uses numbers as references. This is inherited from `plain`.
A style like `plainnat` can be used as the base instead to use `natbib` like Author-Year references instead.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{my.bib}
    @unpublished{Sample,
        Author = {Sample},
        Title = {A Title in Title Case},
        Url = {http://eyample.tld/},
        Year = {0000},
        Note = {Note}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \bibliographystyle{link}
    \nocite{Sample}
    \bibliography{my}
\end{document}
```

[image]